# templates <int T> C++

Tags: c++, templates, non-type-template-parameter

What does it mean to define a template with `template <int N>`, I read this from an example in a book:

```
typedef map<int, double> row;
template <int N> struct matrix;
{
   map <int, row> my_matrix;
}
```

I have usually seen templates which are followed by class and then type, i.e. `template <class int>`

Comment: `template<class int>` is not valid.

Comment: I assume he meant `template<class T>` or `template<typename T>`. The main thrust of the question is useful to me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Template parameters may be of any of the three kinds of C++ entities: values, types, or templates:

```
template <int N> struct Foo;                        // N is a value

template <typename T> struct Bar;                   // T is a type

template <template <typename> class X> struct Zip;  // X is a template
```

Example usage:

```
Foo<10> a;

Bar<int> b;

Zip<Bar> c;
```

Note that this corresponds to the three ways of disamiguating dependent names:

```
X::a = 10;              // X::a is a value
typename X::B n = 10;   // X::B is a type
X::template C<int> m;   // X::C is a template
```

---

An interesting combination arises when you want to "typify" a value. This can be done like so:

```
template <typename T, T Val> struct Typificate;
```

Now you can say e.g. `Typificate<int, 10>` to get a unique type that represents the integer 10. This can occasionally be very useful, e.g. when `T` is a member function pointer (e.g. in [this delegate implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11015/The-Impossibly-Fast-C-Delegates)); or it can be used to create value-unique overloads for tag dispatch, etc.

Comment: I'm still a little confused with the example, suppose we have `template <class name, class type> class row { private: name some_name; type some_type; };` The `class name/type` are used to typify variables defined in the class, however, what is the purpose of having `template <int N> struct Foo;` what is the `"N"` used for?

Comment: @JamesHallen: It can be used for whatever you want. An obvious example is an array size in some custom array template.

Comment: So in such a case, we're not using "N" to typify any variables in the struct, we are using it to initialize an array. For example: `vector<int> my_vector(2);`, using "N" is akin to constructing a vector of size 2

Comment: @JamesHallen: Consider `template <unsigned int N> struct Foo { int a[N]; };`

Comment: Sorry, another question from my code above: if I declared `matrix<5> temp;`, would that create 5 elements of `my_matrix`, in other words I have access to `temp.my_matrix[0]`, `temp.my_matrix[1]`...`temp.my_matrix[4]`?

Comment: @JamesHallen: No, why would it do that -- `matrix<5>` has only one member, `map <int, row> my_matrix`. If you want an array, you need to declare an array.

Answer (score 1):

It will provide a `int` constant value that is evaluated at compile time

```
template <int N> struct matrix {
   static const int MatrixSize = N;
   map <int, row> my_matrix;
};

matrix<10>::MatrixSize; // Yields 10
```

Comment: `typedef` for defining a static integer value?

Comment: @delnan Thank's for pointing out. Of course not `typedef` :P ...

Answer (score 1):

That is a non-type template parameter. A parameter in the parameter list of a template can be either a non-type parameter, a type parameter or a template parameter. In your example it is the first. For more information see [Template parameters and template arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters).

A non-type template argument is normally used to initialize a class or to specify the sizes of class members. According to the standard (14.1 [temp.param]) a non-type template parameter can have one of the following types:

> A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following
>   (optionally cv-qualified) types:
>
> - integral or enumeration type,
> - pointer to object or pointer to function,
> - lvalue reference to object or lvalue reference to function,
> - pointer to member,
> - std::nullptr_t.